# Convert a SQL query into a Linq to SQL instruction

Tags: sql, linq

I need to convert the below SQL query into a Linq query

```
select *
from bancos 
where codigobanco in 
   (select distinct codigobanco
   from headerarquivo
   where (MONTH(datahorageracao)=12) and (YEAR(datahorageracao)=2010))
```

How could I do to transform this SQL query in a Linq query ?

Answer (score 2):

assuming that datahorageracao is a datetime you didnt post the properties or the domain model but want you want is something like this:

```
from banco in bancos
let queryauxiliar = (from arquivo in headerarquivo where (arquivo.datahorageracao.Month = 12) && arquivo.datahorageracao.Year = 2010 select arquivo.codigobanco)
where queryauxiliar.Any((val)=>banco.codigobanco == val.codigobanco)
select new Banco()
{
   NomeProp = banco.valor
}
```

Comment: I got it using Linq to entity
 var bancos = (from ha in ouroDB.HeaderArquivoes
       .Where(h => h.DataHoraGeracao.Month == dtpGeracao.Value.Month)
       .Where(h => h.DataHoraGeracao.Year == dtpGeracao.Value.Year)
      from bc in ouroDB.Bancos
      .Where(b => b.CodigoBanco.Contains(ha.CodigoBanco))
      select bc).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b.NomeBanco);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `datahorageracao` is of type DateTime.Two different ways you can write LINQ code first using [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and second using [query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) syntax either way works -

```
//Lambda Expression way get distinct codigobanco...
var codigobancolist =Context.headerarquivo.Where(c=>c.datahorageracao.Month ==12 && c.datahorageracao.Year==2010).Select(c=>c.codigobanco).Distinct();

//Query Expression way to get actual data...
    var data= from b in bancos 
              where b.codigobanco.Contains(codigobancolist)
              select b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var banco = from c in bancos
            where headerarquivos
                  .Select(o => o.codibanco)
                  .Where(o.MONTH(datahorageracao)=12) and (o.YEAR(datahorageracao)=2010))
                  .Contains(c.codibanco)
            select c;
```

Pretty sure that should do it.

Comment: You need to move `Select(o => o.codibanco)` one line down